# Use of * and & together in function signature

Tags: c++, pointers

I was playing through c++ and trying to understand vector and its signature . 
In below method printPrimes I need to use pointer with address of why ?

Is `vector<int> &primes` not enough as from main method printPrimes is already sending address .

```
void printPrimes(long long l, long long r, vector<int>* &primes) {
 // some code
}
vector<int>* sieve() {

 vector<int> *prime = new vector<int>();
 return prime;

}
int main() {
    vector<int> *primes = sieve();
    printPrimes(l, r, primes);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "In below method printPrimes I need to use pointer with address of why ?" The `&` means reference, not address of.

Comment: In C++ a & in the function parameters means reference and not address like in C. So you are giving a reference of a pointer to this function. A similar effect can be achieved by using a double pointer except that when you call the function you would need to use & to get the address of the pointer.

Comment: why i need to use reference and * together

Comment: The declaration `vector<int>* &primes` declares `primes` to be a reference to a pointer to a `vector` of `int` elements. You might need it if you want to change where the pointer is pointing. It's unlikely you need to do that though, so stop using pointers at all.

Comment: @QuesterDesura: That does not make sense. In C and C++ alike, `&foo` in an expression means "address of foo". But as a function parameter, only C++ has references. Function parameter definitions are not expressions (only the default argument, if present, is an expression)

Comment: @MSalters that is what I was trying to say. The & has 2 uses in C++ while in C it only has one. In C & is used to get the address of something and in C++ it can also be used for references.

Comment: I get a feeling that `printPrimes` does much more than just print some primes. (And `sieve` doesn't do any sieving. Naming is important.)

Comment: @MSalters: It makes complete sense. Perhaps you misread it.

Comment: Can anyone explain with input and output with different scenario

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The statement is that "in C, `&` in a function parameter definition means address". Can you give a C example where that statement is true?

Comment: @MSalters: Where is that statement located?

Comment: @MSalters The statement is that in C++ a & can also mean reference, while in C when you do use a & it is only used to get the address of something.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think he's referring to "& in the function parameters means reference and not address like in C". The way that's written suggests that it means address in the function parameters in C.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In case you missed it, I responded to a misleading comment from QuesterDesura. The question from Sumeet is fine.

Comment: @QuesterDesura: True, but that reuse is possible because the context in which that's done is fundamentally different. In particular, in C++ **declarations** it means "reference". In C and C++, in unary expressions it means address-of. And in binary expressions, it means bitwise-and. You talked about a function parameter, which is a declaration.

Comment: @MSalters: I didn't miss it but you seem to be deliberately misquoting the comment. Either way it's very obvious what was meant and very obvious that the commenter knows what a reference is. So that's the end of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to use pointer with address of

Here, `&` does not mean "address of"; it means the type "reference to".

It's clearer if you write it not like this:

```
vector<int>* &primes
```

but like this:

```
vector<int>*& primes
```

Though the choice of whitespace is artificial, that better documents that this `&` is "part of the type".

Have some types:

- `std::vector<T>` = A vector of `T`s
- `std::vector<T>&` = A reference to a vector of `T`s
- `std::vector<T>*` = A pointer to a vector of `T`s
- `std::vector<T>*&` = A reference to a pointer to a vector of `T`s
- `std::vector<T>***` = A pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a vector of `T`s
- `std::vector<T>**&` = A reference to a pointer to a pointer to a vector of `T`s

…and so forth.

As for *why* you need a `vector<int>*&` for `printPrimes` to do its job, we could not tell you without actually being able to see it. I will say that it seems unlikely it needs a pointer at all, and that if it wants to *modify* that pointer it's going to cause problems with the `new` and `delete` in the calling scope.

In fact, all that dynamic allocation is completely pointless and only complicates things.

The following was likely intended instead:

```
void printPrimes(long long l, long long r, vector<int>& primes) {
 // some code
}
vector<int> sieve() {
 vector<int> prime;
 return prime;

}
int main() {
    vector<int> primes = sieve();
    printPrimes(l, r, primes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++ `&` in function parameter used to pass parameter by reference. `vector<int>* &primes` declares `primes` to be a reference to a pointer to `vector<int>`.

If `printPrimes` means to print only the vector passed to the function then the signature

```
void printPrimes(long long l, long long r, vector<int> &primes);
```

can also do the job.

Reference to a pointer is needed when the pointer passed to the function is need to be modified and it's effect is expected to seen in the caller function.

```
void foo(int*& p){
    p = new int[10]; 
    // rest of the code 
}
```

if a function `bar` is calling `foo` like

```
void bar(/* some parameters */){
    // ...
    int *p;
    foo(p);
    // rest of the code
}
```

`foo` is modifying the pointer itself and this modification will be seen to `bar` also and memory allocated to `p` can be accessed from `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int>* &primes` parameter has to be read this way:

*Reference to a pointer of vector of int*

and not

*Address of a pointer of vector of int* (which, you are right, would be useless)

Passing by reference allows to directly manipulate any instance outside of scope (like with pointers, but a safer way since a reference cannot be `nullptr`, and its existence is auto-managed (no need to delete)).